# Pagina en blanco al crear tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una query que en los logs del servidor web me aparece lo siguiente y no me muestra nada en el Navegador:

> **PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
 include("conn.php");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, COUNT(IF(stat='open',1, NULL)) 'open',
       COUNT(IF(stat='close',1, NULL)) 'close',
       COUNT(IF(stat='all',1, NULL)) 'all',
       COUNT(IF(stat='reopen',1, NULL)) 'reopen',
       COUNT(IF(stat='finish',1, NULL)) 'finish'
FROM dashboard group by name order by name = 'Party' desc");


 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $test['id'];
 echo"<td>".$test['name']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$test['open']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$test['close']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$test['all']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$test['reopen']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$test['finish']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 ?>
```

mientras que si pongo la siguiente query si me aparecen datos:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dashboard");
```

Que me está fallando?

La query funciona si la ejecuto en la consola:

```
+----------+------+-------+-----+--------+--------+
| name     | open | close | all | reopen | finish |
+----------+------+-------+-----+--------+--------+
| Party    |   21 |     0 |   0 |      0 |      0 |
| Party1   |    0 |     0 |   0 |      0 |      0 |
| Party2   |    0 |     0 |   0 |      0 |      0 |
| Party3   |    2 |     0 |   0 |      0 |      0 |
+----------+------+-------+-----+--------+--------+
```

actualizo con datos de la tabla:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| stat        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

En el momento que aparece el error **Unknown column 'stat' in 'field list'** valido que si existe:

```
MariaDB [rt2]> select stat from dashboard where stat = 'finish' limit 1;
+---------+
| stat    |
+---------+
| finish  |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: si usas esa consulta en la consola de mysql si te funciona? es decir te regresa resultados?

Comment: me parece que después de esta parte en tu query te hace falta mandar como segundo parametro el nombre de la variable que tiene tu conexión: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, COUNT(IF(stat='open',1, NULL)) 'open',
       COUNT(IF(stat='close',1, NULL)) 'close',
       COUNT(IF(stat='all',1, NULL)) 'all',
       COUNT(IF(stat='reopen',1, NULL)) 'reopen',
       COUNT(IF(stat='finish',1, NULL)) 'finish'
FROM dashboard group by name order by name = 'Party' desc", $conexion);`

Comment: es decir yo puse de ejemplo `$conexion` pero tu agrega como se llama la variable que contiene dicha conexion

Comment: Parece que tu 1ª consulta es errónea. Por ejemplo, en tu `SELECT *` no aparece una columna `stat`, la cual usas en la consulta que falla. ¿Esa columna existe en `dashboard`?

Comment: @A.Cedano si. Existe. He actualizado con información el post original

Comment: @shadow no es necesario añadir el parametro pues ya establezco conexion dentro de conn.php y con la query del "*" me funciona...

Comment: @GuifIf hasta donde yo sabia si era necesario por que `mysql_query()` espera dos parametros, pero igual revisaré

Comment: @shadow Guif tiene razón, si no se especifica la conexión, adquiere la última usada o intenta conectarse de nuevo. Guif, somete la consulta a un control de errores, haciendo esto: `if ($result = mysql_query( ... aqui la query ...) { //aquí el código que tienes en caso de que funcione  } else { echo mysql_error(); }` Siempre es bueno no dar por hecho que una consulta va a funcionar...

Comment: me aparece el error **Unknown column 'stat' in 'field list'**

Comment: Oye el mensaje de error es claro: dice que la columna `stat` no existe en la tabla. Entonces ¿en qué quedamos, existe o no existe esa columna?

Comment: actualizado topic con mas datos. existe